# Reading history on the server ejabberd (mnesia)

Tags: ejabberd, mnesia

Good afternoon. The server ejabberd writes history to the standard database Mnesia. How can an administrator view this story? Didn't find any information anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `archive_msg` mnesia table used by [mod_mam](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-mam) to implement
[XEP-0313: Message Archive Management](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html), then the answer is: this is for XMPP clients to get their chat history, not for admins for spying their users.

Still, you can view the mnesia table content in ejabberd's WebAdmin -> Nodes -> your node -> Database -> archive_msg table -> Elements

By the way, if you plan to use MAM, over the years, with many users, then you should use a SQL database instead of Mnesia, because Mnesia is only intended for storing a few data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
For some reason, when viewing the table through the WebAdmin, the user's correspondence written in Cyrillic is displayed like this: {xmlcdata,
                   <<208,148,208,176,209,128,208,190,208,178,208,176>>}]
Latin is displayed correctly. What could be causing this?
And another question: what happens when the size of 2GB is reached with the database?

Comment: Right, this happens with any string that contains non-latin characters, it's a formatting problem in that webadmin page. Better not to fill mnesia database with so many data; you better migrate it to SQL if your server starts to grow. No idea what will happen.